# Plotting audio from librosa in matplotlib

Tags: python, audio, matplotlib, plot, librosa

I am trying to plot the waveform of an audio file in Python.

This is my code (I am using the Librosa library):

```
import plot as plt

def save_plot(filename):
    y, sr = librosa.load(filename)        
    plt.plot(y, 'audio', 'time', 'amplitude')
```

Where the plot.py file is:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

def plot(vector, name, xlabel=None, ylabel=None):
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(vector)
    plt.xlabel(xlabel)
    plt.ylabel(ylabel)
    plt.plot()
    plt.savefig('static/plots/' + name)
```

The weird thing is that, even though I get a plot that seems like a valid waveform:
[image: waveform]

The audio file is only 5 seconds long. Therefore, I don't understand what the x axis is talking about; it seems to go up to 90000?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The waveform will have a data point at every time your audio file is sampled, they can be sampled from 8000 Hz to 48 kHz. 90,000/5 = 18000 Hz.

Look at the variable you're currently ignoring from librosa.load, that is the sampling rate, which will let you figure out the timescale.

Comment: Thanks! Just to be sure I got it, my sampling rate is approx. 22000. Does that mean that, because my audio file is 5 seconds, the x axis represents the 22000*5 = 110000 samples that were taken, and not time?

Comment: @pk1914 "approx. 22000" is a strange thing to say about the sampling rate of a "normal" sound file. Does it happen to be (exactly) 22050?

Comment: You are right! I guess it is a special number? Why so? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is why you're using `matplotlib.pyplot` to plot your vector, which contains many terms as it (probably) samples 22050 data points per second. If you got an audio file with 5 seconds then you get 5 * 22050 = 110250 data points, which will be plotted in the figure. Instead of using `matplotlib.pyplot` you can just use the proper way to do this with `librosa`:

```
import librosa
import librosa.display

y, sr = librosa.load(<path_audio_file>, sr=<sample_rate>)
fig, ax = librosa.display.waveplot(y, sr=sr)
```

As it retains the sample rate as information, then it will normalize the time series at the right time length!

Note that for using `librosa.display` you need to explicitly import it.

If you're interested in more details check [librosa.display.waveplot](https://librosa.org/doc/main/generated/librosa.display.waveplot.html).

Comment: `librosa.display.waveplot()` was deprecated in librosa 0.8.1 and removed in 0.9.0, it was replaced and extended by `librosa.display.waveshow()`.